# Delete specific values from column with where condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I want to delete specific values/data from one column with the WHERE condition. Putting in another way, I don't want to delete the complete row. Is it possible?

Comment: Please include a sample what you have got now.

Answer (score 60):

```
UPDATE YourTable SET columnName = null WHERE YourCondition
```

Answer (score 28):

```sql
UPDATE myTable 
   SET myColumn = NULL 
 WHERE myCondition
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 19):

You don't want to *delete* if you're wanting to leave the row itself intact. You want to *update* the row, and change the column value.

The general form for this would be an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE <table name>
SET
    ColumnA = <NULL, or '', or whatever else is suitable for the new value for the column>
WHERE
    ColumnA = <bad value> /* or any other search conditions */
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `REPLACE()`:

```sql
UPDATE Table
   SET Column = REPLACE(Column, 'Test123', 'Test')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL statement:

```sql
update Table set Column =( Column - your val )
```