# Want to delete specific column in a table

Tags: sql

I want to delete specific values/data from one column with the WHERE condition. Putting in another way, I don't want to delete the complete row. Is it possible?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and a better explanation of what you want to do.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732838/delete-specific-values-from-column-with-where-condition

Comment: Do you want to remove values from the column (e.g. set them to `NULL`)  or do you want to alter the table so that the column is no longer accessible?

Answer (score 1):

You can re-set values using `update`:

```
update t
    set col = NULL
    where . . .;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to delete the particular value/data from the column using WHERE condition. You can use the below code in SQL command to delete that particular column.

```
  Update Table_Name set Column_Name=null where Column_Id=xxx
```

or you can even update that by changing the Column_name value to an empty string   ' ' Like below

```
  Update Table_Name set Column_Name='' where Column_Id=xxx
```